# 32" 4K monitor for office work

Tags: monitors, 4k

What's the best 32" 4K monitor for office work when considering price?

It should have a height adjustable stand and should be VESA mountable.

Also, it should have a DisplayPort input.

IPS preferred, but not required.

Comment: I have more than a few recommendations that come to mind. What VESA dimensions would you like (75 x 75, 100 x 100)? Also what would your upper price limit be, or would you prefer I just default to maximum price reduction?

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion on the VESA dimensions, as long as it has a mount; 100x00 and 75x75 both seem suitable. I am keen to not spend more than AU$700.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Australian markets, do you guys typically list prices as USD or in AU? The cheapest monitor I could bring down for your locale is $558.00, but I'm not sure whether it's in USD or AU. E.g. [a site like this](https://www.shoppingexpress.com.au/)

Comment: We exclusively list prices in AUD.

Comment: I've done a [comprehensive analysis exactly on this, 32" 4K (UHD) monitors](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13608/32-curved-4k-uhd-ips-monitor-with-adjustable-stand). Updated as of CES 2021.

Answer (score 1):

### [AOC - U3277PWQU | AU $558.00](https://www.shoppingexpress.com.au/buy/aoc-u3277pwqu-32-4k-uhd-professional-led-monitor/U3277PWQU)

[image: AOC U3277PWQU]

- W-LED **3840 x 2160 p**
- **VESA Interface: 100 x 100 mm**
- **Height Adjustment Range: 180 mm**
- **DisplayPort 1.2 x 1**
- Exact Dimension: 31.5"
- Flicker Free Technology
- Refresh Rate: 60 Hz
- Response Time: 4 ms

[[See Comprehensive Spec List Here]](https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/model/6ef26a6)

---

Regarding IPS requirement: Monitors in this price range and resolution are pretty much exclusively LED. IPS is a technology used in LCD to mimic LED properties.

### [[Track Cheapest Price for model here]](https://au.pcpartpicker.com/product/H2tWGX/aoc-u3277pwqu-320-3840x2160-60hz-monitor-u3277pwqu)